# Multiple functions in an onChange? Answers I've seen aren't working

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to do multiple things when an onChange event happens. I've seen some other answers, but all of them are giving the error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression".

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function useDebounce(value, delay) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const handler = setTimeout(() => {
        setDebouncedValue(value);
      }, delay);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(handler);
      };
    },
    [value, delay],
  );

  return debouncedValue;
}

function App() {

  const [cardNames, setCardName] = useState([]);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("pikachu");
  const debouncedInput = useDebounce(searchInput, 1000)

  const rezCards = async () => {
    const rez = await fetch('https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name='+searchInput+'')
    const json = await rez.json()
    setCardName(json.cards)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    rezCards()
  },[debouncedInput])

  return <aside>
    <p>Search Term: {searchInput}</p>
    <form>
      <input id="search-field" type="text" value={searchInput} onChange = {
          searchCard => setSearchInput(searchCard.target.value)
        }></input>
    </form>
    <hr />
    <ul>
      {cardNames
      .map(
        (cardName) => {
          return <li key={cardName.id}><img src={cardName.imageUrl} /><span className="poke-cardname">{cardName.name}</span></li>
        }
      )}
    </ul>
    </aside>
}

export default App
```

The line is the onChange in the #search-field input. I've tried this:

```
<input id="search-field" type="text" value={searchInput} onChange = {
          () => { searchCard => setSearchInput(searchCard.target.value); console.log("Test"); }
}></input>
```

(The console.log could be anything, such as another function. It doesn't matter, the error is always the same.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were missing curly brackets around the multiple functions you want triggered. Without the brackets you are implying a return value (the first function) only.

```
<input onChange={
  (searchCard) => {
    setSearchInput(searchCard.target.value);
    console.log("Test");
  }
}></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchCard => setSearchInput(searchCard.target.value); console.log("Test");
---Problem is Here.


<input id="search-field" type="text" value={searchInput} onChange = {
              (searchCard) =>  {

                          setSearchInput(searchCard.target.value); 
                          console.log("Test"); 
              }
    }></input>
```